# Make crontab inside Dockerfile not working

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile

I create a `crontab` file like this

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

and a `Dockerfile` like this

```
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

I checked inside container by command `service cron status`

```
[ ok ] cron is running.
```

and `crontab -l`

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

All of that look like ok but when I `tail -f /var/log/cron.log` nothing to happen, how to fix that thank

Comment: you can try installing syslog-ng to get a the /var/log/syslog file which might show any errors that occured when cron tried to run

Comment: How are you starting the container?  "Checked inside the container, running `service ...`" seems suspicious to me, since normally a container doesn't run an interactive shell or an init system, and `service` doesn't really work in this environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze I using `docker compose build` and after that is up, i go inside container by `docker exec -it ...`. Update: If I remove all line in `Dockerfile` and do manually using `crontab -e ...` and `service cron start` inside container it working :(. But it too manually :(